# VSCode Salesforce evaluate function not working

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, salesforce, apex

After starting the apex replay debugger and when try to evaluate a field (right click then Debug: Evaluate), VS Code displays on the debug console the exact same text I highlighted for evaluation 
e.g: 
loan.LLC_BI__Product__c --> is showing up in the debug console instead of the value of LLC_BI__Product__c

can you please help - please see image attached

thanks

[image: See detail by clicking here]

Comment: Are you following these instructions? https://forcedotcom.github.io/salesforcedx-vscode/articles/apex/replay-debugger

Comment: it does not seems to be supported at this time - thanks for your help